# Given partial key exposure and encryption oracle, can we recover full AES key?

Tags: aes, chosen-plaintext-attack

Suppose I have an encryption oracle for AES with some key $k$ (16 bytes) and that I know $n$ bytes of it. Is it possible to recover the rest ($16 - n$) in complexity less than $256^{16-n}$?

Comment: @kelalaka but this is not faster than $256^{16-n}$ (I corrected myself).

Comment: Your writing style is strange, anyway $256^{16-n} = 2^{128-8\cdot n}$. What is the value of n? if n = 5,6,7,8....15-btye then brute force works.

Comment: @kelalaka $n$ can be between $1$ and $15$. I'm interested if there are some publications on this topic. Brute force will not deliver the answer *faster* than brute force - $256^{16-n}$ is exactly the time needed by brute force. I don't know how should it be possible to brute it with $n = 5$, as $256^{16-5} = 256^11 = 2^88$, which is totally too big. It becomes manageable with $n = 11$.

Comment: Bitcoin mining reached $\approx 2^{91}$  SHA-256 mining in one year. [Summit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298) can reach $2^{73}$ in one year.

Comment: @kelalaka I mean breaking it by myself :c

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no known easier attack than doing a brute force search on the unknown key bits.

In particular, if there were, then this show an attack on the standard (no key bits leaked) AES, because what an attacker could do is go through all possible $2^{8n}$ settings of those key bits, assume those, and run his 'less-than-brute-force' attack on the remaining key bits.  If this attack (when his guess for the 'known' key bits is correct) takes an expected time of less than the time taken to compute $2^{128 - 8n-1}$ AES evaluations, then the total time will take less than the time taken to do $2^{128-1}$ evaluations, that is, it shows that there is a faster-than-generic attack

Comment: But you assume known plaintext attack, while I'm talking about a decryption oracle. Well, I wouldn't be surprised if this doesn't change much here, but nevertheless, your answer doesn't address it.

Comment: @enedil We kinda assume known plaintext attacks by default when addressing this kind of issue, but you're right, it does seem to be missing.