# Length Extension attacks in SHA1 and MD5?

Tags: sha-1, length-extension

From my understanding on the internet about length-extension attack, I have understood that **hash(secret_key|known_data)** can be exploited to produce **hash(secret_key|known_data|appended_data)** even without knowing the exact value of the **secret_key** by just knowing the length of the key. I tried implementing this using **hashpumpy** python module and this did not match.

```
import os
import sys
import hashpumpy

secret_key="secretkey"
known_data="data"
appended_data="append"

hash_1="9885f8af04289135df259e34bd22d17fe45ea81e" # hash of secret_key+known_data
hash_2="e9163e43652a921df34f76e635d32f6aad1286b8" # hash of secret_key+known_data+appended_data

new_hash,msg=hashpumpy.hashpump(hash_1,'data','append',len(secret_key))
print(new_hash,msg)
```

Output:

> 475bdd96a25e7717842072c5be2944076ba31143
>   b'data\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00happend'

But the hash I want to calculate is of **secretdataappend**

Answer (score 5):

You forget one little step of how [Merkle–Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) works; the padding, here SHA-1 [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Examples_and_pseudocode):

> append the bit $\texttt{1}$ to the message e.g. by adding $\texttt{0x80}$ if message length (*ml*) is a multiple of 8 bits.

> append $0 \leq k < 512$ bits $\texttt{0}$, such that the resulting message length in bits is congruent to $$−64 \equiv 448 \pmod{512}$$

> append *ml*, the original message length, as a 64-bit big-endian integer.
> Thus, the total length is a multiple of 512 bits.

Therefore the real input is

$$\text{SHA-1}(\text{secret_key}\mathbin\|\text{known_data}\mathbin\|pad1)$$

because the attackers only get the hashed value. And, you need

$$\text{SHA-1}(\text{secret_key}\mathbin\|\text{known_data}\mathbin\| \text{pad1}\mathbin\| 
 \text{appended_data} \mathbin\| \text{pad2})$$

for extension attack. This works similarly for any hash function that uses the same padding mechanism.

The attackers can access the hash of a padded message and they can extend it in this way. This is due to the artifact of Merkle–Damgård construction. SHA-3 is safe from this attack by design and later the new SHA2 modes SHA512/256 and SHA512/384 and other truncated versions of SHA2 also have resistance to length extension attacks.

[SHA-1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76879/in-2020-sha-1-practically-broken-in-chosen-prefix-collision-cp-collision-can) or [MD5](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1434/18298) is not considered secure. Use modern Hash functions like SHA3 or Blake2 with large output sizes like 256-bit to prevent generic collision attacks, classic or quantum.