# How to get an output of SHA-1 with first 2-bit are zeros?

Tags: hash, sha-1

Can someone explain what are the ways to get an output of SHA-1 with first 2-bits which are zeros?

Comment: Interestingly, your question is more or less is the bitcoin nonce problem

Comment: Just bruteforce it? Or are there assumptions made on the input for the hash function?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hash random values until you get a hash with two leading zeroes. We would expect  about 1 in 4 values to have a hash-value of that form.

So let's try this:

```
echo hello | sha1sum
f572d396fae9206628714fb2ce00f72e94f2258f  -
```

Nope.

```
echo hello1 | sha1sum
0ef562ff2d0c21358f9d289f1c908436714fc923  -
```

There we are, 4 leading zeroes.

Comment: Isn't it 1/16, rather than 1/4?

Comment: We're talking about *two* leading zeroes, so it's $1/2^2=1/4$. Maybe you're confused because my example has 4 leading zeroes? That just happened to be the first one I found. (After 2 tries.)

Comment: yep! that's exactly why. Sorry :)

Comment: @hanshenrik I have no idea what your code is doing, but given that 0x0e is 00001110 in binary, it clearly has 4 leading zeroes. I think you are either checking for trailing zeroes and/or interpreting things as little endian instead of big endian.

Comment: The following python code agrees with my shell: from hashlib import sha1
hashvalue = sha1('hello1\n'.encode('utf-8')).digest()
print(format(int.from_bytes(hashvalue,'big'),'0=160b'))

Answer (score 13):

This is an extension of [Maeher's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83225/18298) and the full code of this answer is in [Github](https://github.com/kelalaka153/SHA-1-LeadingZeroes).

Hash functions are expected to produce random output random in the sense that the value of the hash is basically unpredictable without actual computing. We, also, expect them to produce the hash result evenly, i.e. all possible hash values occur with the same probability. This means that we expect 1/2 of them to have a leading zero, 1/4 them has 2 leading zeroes, and so on. In a formal way; for $n$ trial we expect $n/2^i$ values have $i$-leading zero.

The below Python code experiment this (the below is optimized of the original. It is optimized [on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/247486/185475) at least 2x speed up )

```
import hashlib
import random

leading = [0] * 160

for i in range(100000):
    
    hashvalue = hashlib.sha1(random.getrandbits(128).to_bytes(16, 'big')).digest()
    zeroes = 160 - int.from_bytes(hashvalue, 'big').bit_length()
    leading[zeroes] = leading[zeroes] +1
    
for item in leading: 
    print(item, end =',')
```

Sample output is

`1     2     3    4    5    6   7   8   9  10`
`49894,25040,12555,6251,3142,1523,787,392,202,111,49,21,10,10,6,2,3,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,...`

the remaining all zero...

The graph of the event.

[image]

Note that it is possible to draw this together with $n/2^i$, however, they are so close to each other that one needs to zoom.

The below is the $\log_{1000}$ scaled $y$ axis with $10^{10} \approx 32$-bits random trials, 1K times more than above, took around 3 hours. With the result data

`4999899716,2500040694,1250025163,625012247,312519435,156242195,78129201,39070485,19532263,9766270,4882962,2438565,1220675,610279,305021,152313,75950,38232,19141,9601,4800,2403,1200,610,305,127,75,32,16,15,4,3,2,0,0,...`

This time the with $n/2^i$, which is reddish. Since the event is so small compared to space, most of the values are 0 that is the reason for the drop of blue.

[image]

A zoom on the initial part is the below figure.

[image]

This tells us that how SHA-1 outputs are close to ideal. We already know that is necessary but not sufficient and the [attacks on SHA-1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76879/18298) verifies this.

And, if you replace the SHA-1 with double SHA256 one will see the hardness of mining.

---

Below is the python code that searches and prints for given leading zero.

```
def searchAndPrint(numberOfTrials,leadingZero):
    for i in range(numberOfTrials): 
        rndValue = random.getrandbits(128).to_bytes(16, 'big')
        hashvalue = hashlib.sha1(rndValue).digest()
        
        if leadingZero == (160 - int.from_bytes(hashvalue, 'big').bit_length()):
            print(bin(int.from_bytes(rndValue, byteorder='big'))[2:].zfill(128), " ", bin(int.from_bytes(hashvalue, byteorder='big'))[2:].zfill(160))

searchAndPrint(numberOfTrials,2)
```

---

Plotting part as per [request](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/83224/how-to-get-an-output-of-sha-1-with-first-2-bit-are-zeros/83227?noredirect=1#comment182706_83227);

```
def expectedGraphData(space,div2):    
    for idx,item in enumerate(div2) : 
        div2[idx] = space /pow(2,idx+1)
        

def plotTheGraph(a_list, leading,div2):
    plt.plot(a_list,leading)
    plt.plot(a_list,div2)
    plt.title('SHA-1 Leading Zeroes')
    plt.xlabel('Leading Zeroes')
    plt.ylabel('Count log_1000')
    plt.yscale('log',base=1000)
    plt.show()

xAxislist = list(range(1, 161))
expectedValues   = [0] * 160

expectedGraphData(numberOfTrials,expectedValues)

plotTheGraph(xAxislist,leadingZeros, expectedValues)
```

Comment: If ever a plot called for a log axis, it's this.

Comment: Should "9894" be "49894"?

Comment: Your graphs say *trailing* zeros, but your code appears to be counting leading zeros.  Did you actually count trailing for the grap, or is that a mistake?  e.g. hex `7ab100` has 3 leading zero bits, 8 trailing 0 bits.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the notification. A new was coming, but I need to break it now due to your notice. Anyway, faster code can run now.

Comment: `Hash functions are expected to produce random output.` — better phrasing would be something like `evenly/uniformly distributed`. Random function would be a quite bad hash function.

Comment: @user28434 random output is usually considered as we expect them to emulate the random oracle. But we expect them to distribute the output uniformly, and that was the main point of the answer. I'll clarify more about that part. By the way, actually, by a hash design, we are chosen a random function from all possible ones, and eliminate those who are not good for Cryptography. That is similar for the block ciphers, too, where a key selects a random permutation from all possible permutations. --Thanks.

Comment: @kelalaka could you perchance add in the last bit of code that generates the three above graphs?

Comment: @haneefmubarak full code at [github](https://github.com/kelalaka153/SHA-1-LeadingZeroes)

Answer (score 1):

just bruteforce it;
one possible way to do it in PHP would be:

... i'm not sure which way to count the bits, code to count them in both directions follows:

---

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

$bit1_flag = 1 << 7;
$bit2_flag = 1 << 6;
// (and i know the fugly for loop should be a do{}while() instead, anyone feel free to fix it, idc)
for ($i = 0; $i < PHP_INT_MAX; ++ $i) {
    $str = (string) $i;
    $hash = hash("sha1", $str, true);
    $ord = ord($hash[0]);
    if (($ord & $bit1_flag) || ($ord & $bit2_flag)) {
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

function strtobits(string $str): string
{
    $ret = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++ $i) {
        $ord = ord($str[$i]);
        for ($bitnum = 7; $bitnum >= 0; -- $bitnum) {
            if ($ord & (1 << $bitnum)) {
                $ret .= "1";
            } else {
                $ret .= "0";
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
var_dump($str, strtobits($hash), bin2hex($hash));
```

which prints

```
string(1) "1"
string(160) "0011010101101010000110010010101101111001000100111011000001001100010101000101011101001101000110001100001010001101010001101110011000111001010101000010100010101011"
string(40) "356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab"
```

it seems SHA1("1") starts with 2x zero bits

---

-OR- alternative code counting bits in the other direction...:

---

```
<?php

    $bit1_flag= 1 << 0;
    $bit2_flag= 1 << 1;
    // (and i know the fugly for loop should be a do{}while() instead, anyone feel free to fix it, idc)
    for($i=0;$i<PHP_INT_MAX;++$i){
        $str=(string)$i;
        $hash=hash("sha1",$str,true);
        $ord=ord($hash[0]);
        if(($ord & $bit1_flag) || ($ord & $bit2_flag)){
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    function strtobits(string $str):string{
        $ret="";
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);++$i){
            $ord=ord($str[$i]);
            for($bitnum=0;$bitnum<8;++$bitnum){
                if($ord & (1<<$bitnum)){
                    $ret.="1";
                }else{
                    $ret.="0";
                }
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    var_dump($str,strtobits($hash),bin2hex($hash));
```

which prints

```
string(1) "5"
string(160) "0011010100101100000111100110101101011001001111001000000101011111010001100110011111110000001110100110110001101001011010000101101001110010011110100101011000100011"
string(40) "ac3478d69a3c81fa62e60f5c3696165a4e5e6ac4"
```

it seems sha1("5") starts with 2x zero bits

Comment: The order of bits you're using is rather odd. You're using big-endian byte order, but little endian bit-order if I'm reading this correctly. With big-endian we have 0xac = b'10101100 with no leading zeroes.

Comment: @Maeher hmm interesting, what about https://3v4l.org/uqPru ?

Comment: That seems to agree with my code. (At the end of the day it doesn't really matter which bits you interpret as "first" bits. If there were any significant bias in one of the bits, we would know about it.)

Comment: Python beats in the simplicity :)