# SHA-256 security for initial 32 bits

Tags: sha-256, birthday-attack

I have concerns regarding truncated SHA-256 hashes in an application I am building at the moment:

Nomenclature

`secret` - the full 256-bit SHA-256 result of hashing 16 random bytes
`public` - a unique identifier for an object.
`hash` - the output of `SHA-256(secret || - || public)`
`prefix` - the first 8 characters (32-bit) of hex encoded `hash`.

---

Scenario

`secret` is generated once and remains constant throughout the lifecycle of the scenario.
It is **not known** to the attacker

Identifiers for all objects (`publics`) are **known** to the attacker.

`prefix` will be the base for further computation and information retrieval for a given object.
The first 4 bytes (32 bit) of `hash` have to be sufficient for that.

It is important that a potential attacker cannot generate a valid `prefix` for a given `public`.

---

Concerns

The attacker's utopia is to find `secret` so they can generate a valid `hash` for every object.
This is unrealistic to brute force (computation would take forever).

However, because only the first 32 bit of `hash` matter, is there a mechanic / cryptographic attribute, that makes it feasible for the attacker to guess / compute a valid `secret` that would allow them to generate `prefix` values for given `publics`?

---

Example

```
secret = 'af8b81c94d68...' (256-bit)
public = '123456'
hash = 'fe13c815ab44...' (256-bit)
prefix = hash[0...8] = 'fe13c815'
```

Can the attacker guess `secret` such that they would end up with a valid `prefix`?

Can the attacker use that guessed, validated `secret` and compute `prefix` values for different `publics`?

Comment: "potential attacker cannot generate a valid `prefix` for a given `public"; how do you define a valid prefix?  What is the validation process to check if a prefix is valid?  If the attacker just picks an arbitrary value for the prefix, how do we know that it's not valid?

Answer (score 2):

> Can the attacker guess secret such that they would end up with a valid prefix?
>
> Can the attacker use that guessed, validated secret and compute prefix values for different publics?

You don't need a collision attack here. You need the pre-image attack that given a hash value $h$ one needs to find an $x$ such that $h = \operatorname{SHA-256}(x)$. Note that the attacker doesn't need to find the original value, **any value** that has the required has value will be a success for the pre-image attack and there can be more than one value or none in the range $[0..2^{256}]$. We expect that some will have none due to the collisions.

The 16 bytes hex string makes 128-bit and that is beyond the search for anyone. Therefore looking for **the original value** will be beyond any attacker since there is no known successful pre-image attack better than searching for SHA-256.

Since you trimmed the result, the pre-image resistance now requires around the 32-bit search to find one. The attacker will look for a candidate secret so that

$$\operatorname{SHA-256}(\operatorname{SHA-256}(\text{candidate secret}) \mathbin\|\text{-} \mathbin\| \text{public})$$ will produce valid output.

Once a successful candidate is found, unlikely to be the original since it was the output of SHA-256, the system will accept this a valid input. The attacker only needs to look for the first 32-bit of a 224-bit where they can set the rest bits to zero.

$$\text{candidate secret} = \overbrace{\texttt{0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF}}^{32 \;bits}\;\overbrace{\texttt{0x00000...0}}^{224 \;bits}$$

That search is quite double if you consider some of the [top machines](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298)

1. Summit can reach $\approx 2^{63}$ SHA-1 hashes around one hour, $\approx 2^{72}$ hashes in one year.
2. Titan can reach $\approx 2^{63}$ SHA-1 hashes around two hours, $\approx 2^{71}$ hashes in one year.
3. Bitcoin miners reached $\approx 2^{92}$ SHA-256 hashes per year in 06 Agust 2019.

**The advice:** keep the result at least 16 bytes if you don't fear a possible future quantum attack. Otherwise one needs to double size for [Grover's attack](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9605043) and triple size for [Brassard et.al](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705002)'s attack. Of course, it is not clear how one can prepare the sequential evaluation without a magnificent delay that can cause an invisibility.

Comment: @MaximilianKraus better now? You can delete unnecessary comments.

Comment: Thank you for your perseverance, first of all :)
Wouldn't _candidate secret_ be the already hashed random 16 bytes? The way you wrote it in your answer suggests the attacker tries to find _candidate secret_, then hashes it, adds the public suffix and hashes again. Also 16 bytes does not add up to the bit-wise explanation you gave (16*8 = 128bit, candidate secret is 256bit in your illustration). So those two parts of your answer don't match?

Comment: Why is it that the attacker only has to search for the initial 32bits in order to find a valid output for the outer hash? That would only make sense to me, if the first 32bits of the hash output depend solely on the first 32bits of the input (which is obviously not true). How would the behavior change if the structure of the outer hash would be SHA-256(public || - || secret)?