# How long would it take to brute force a 32 or 16 bit integer and which type of processor would brute force this in the shortest period of time

Tags: brute-force-attack

I was actually wondering... How long would it take to crack/brute force a 32 bit key/encryption and a 16 bit key/encryptions respectively on a 4GHZ and a 2GHZ PC. I know that a 32 bit integer has 4,294,967,296 combinations while a 16 bit number has exactly 65,536 combinations but I don't know how long It'll take. and what processor would be able to brute force this in the shortest period of time

Comment: probably less than a second on any modern system, hell a smart phone could do it in under a second i bet.

Comment: @RichieFrame Even an Intel 4004 could "break" a 16-bit integer in the blink of an eye.

Comment: @forest I am making the assumption that a key scheduling algorithm needs to be run for each key, in the context of an algorithm that uses 32-bit keys, or a truncated key for AES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4,294,967,296ops/4,000,000,000ops/s=1.07s$

$65,535ops/4,000,000,000ops/s=16.4μs$

2GHz twice that.

That's per-core. So 8 cores = 1/8 of a second or so. 64-core/128 thread 2GHz Threadripper = about 16ms.

A GPU will be even faster. It's recommended to brute force the entire 2^32 space for testing various numerical functions, it's fast and catches all the edge cases you might not have thought about. Brute forcing 2^64 values takes a month or so on a fast GPU, easily doable faster on a GPU cluster.

Edit, thanks to kelalaka: a [Tesla V100](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298) can run about $2^{47}$ SHA-1 hashes/hour. SO $720hours/month\times2^{47}Hashes/hour\approx2^{56}Hash/month$. That's about 182 months total, but each hash is substantially more work than just incrementing an integer, so a faster operation can likely be brute-forced in a month on such a GPU. Slower operations need a cluster, but such clusters can be rented from various cloud providers.

Comment: Actually, for an integer that small, a GPU will be significantly slower.

Comment: Do you have a reference for a (single) GPU that could make $2^{64}$ operations in a month? That seems a lot. And what kind of operation? For brute force to be a method worth any consideration, that operation must use several instructions; I can't imagine anything below 4 arithmetic instructions.

Comment: [Tesla V-100](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298) working on SHA-1 does $2^{35}\,\text{Hash/second}\approx2^{47}\,\text{Hash/hour}$ [***note***: the present comment was edited by a moderator per the author's request; it was also removed a later comment based on the earlier, incorrect version]

Comment: Per my number crunching based on a Tesla-V100 doing a [reported](https://gist.github.com/Chick3nman/4d3c5fd44f33610ddbbf026d46d9e0aa) $56\,\text G\,\text H/\text s$ on an MD5 workload, I get $2^{57}$ per month, which is reasonably in line with $2^{64}$ much simpler but still meaningful crypto operations per month. I had not realized that we reached this landmark.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty ridiculous. And things are only expected to get faster. I expect brute-force testing of fast math operations to get more common, since it's an easy way to discover edge cases without having to think them up. Like fuzz testing, but checking all the values instead of random sampling.

Comment: Also, see  https://qberty.com/nvidia-rtx-3090-hashcat-benchmark/ and https://qberty.com/nvidia-rtx-3090-hashcat-benchmark/ I would not update my answer, however, you can benefit from them.

Comment: Yep, and AMD is releasing their next generation GPUs soon, which are expected to be even a bit faster (if you believe AMD's marketing). 6 Nvidia 3090s will be faster than 1x Tesla V-100 for a similar price (and appropriate workload). $2^{64}$ operations just isn't that many these days, even for rather complex operations.

Comment: Thanks, it's easy to forget things like that and just answer the question.

Comment: The links are doubled, sorry, I've updated my answer adding a small table on the middle that you can use the table and see the sources. too.