# Complexity of Hash mining/signing

Tags: hash, complexity, preimage-resistance, proof-of-work

While reading about mining in crypto currency, I found that it requires some leading bits of a hash function output to be 0. This boils down to preimage resistance of the hash function, hence done with exhaustive search.

My question, say I have an ideal hash function that gives 128 bit output and I want leading 4 bits be 0. What is the expected number of time I have to run it (with randomly chosen messages) so that I get a desired outcome?

More specifically, I am looking for a function sort of, that will give the complexity, for setting $m$ bits of an ideal hash function that returns $n$ bits as output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SHA-512 - How difficult is it to find a hash digest beginning with at least twelve zeros?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/89690/sha-512-how-difficult-is-it-to-find-a-hash-digest-beginning-with-at-least-twel)

Comment: @kelalaka thanks  for linking. That one is more empirical, but I want some theoretical calculation

Comment: We already lost when we model is as uniform random. Apart from that, the answer is already theoretical. If you are looking for the expected value, that is easy; It is Bernoulli Trials and the expected value is $p$ and the result is 1/16. The expected value for the number of independent trials to get the first success is $1/p = 16$

Comment: Also note that, when we say complexity, it should be depend on the input other than it is just quantification like a cryptographic hash function expected to have $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$  pre-image security and SHA-256 has 256-bit pre-image security not $\mathcal{O}(2^{256})$ since that is constant!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a random input. Each bit has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ to be zero.
Then because we suppose independence (ideal hash function implies this assumption). For each input the probability to have $4$ zeros in the leading bits is  $\frac{1}{2^4}=\frac{1}{16}$.

Then after $k$ computations, because we consider each output is independent (still because it's an ideal hash function). The probability to wait exactly $i$ steps is a good output is $\frac{1}{16}\left(15/16\right)^{i-1}$. (because you have a wrong output for $(i-1)$ hashes, and then a goof one).

And the expectation of the time of computation is $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} i\frac{1}{16}\left(15/16\right)^{i-1}=
\frac{1}{16}\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \sum^{\infty}_{i=j}\left(15/16\right)^{i-1}= \frac{1}{16}\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\left(15/16\right)^{j+i-1}$

$$=\frac{1}{16}\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \left(15/16\right)^{j-1}\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}\left(15/16\right)^{i}  $$
$$= \frac{1}{16}\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \left(15/16\right)^{j-1}\frac{1}{1/16}$$
$$=\sum^{\infty}_{j=0} \left(15/16\right)^{j}
=16$$.

Then in average you have to compute $16$ hashes to find a good one.

You can easily generalize this proof by replacing $16$ by $2^m$, and you will deduce that in average you need to compute $2^m$ hashes.

Notice that because we choose by advance the coordinates where we want to have the zeros, the total output of the hash function doesn't matter if we look the number of hashes we should compute (but it could do if we look the time of computation of $H$).

Comment: Hmm. So you need $2^m$ random trials to expect a hash output where $m$ locations are fixed.

Comment: Yes, but it's an average.