# Approximate size of image of SHA512

Tags: preimage-resistance, sha-512

Let $s: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{512}$ be the SHA512 hash (where $\{0,1\}^*$ is the countable set of all finite $\{0,1\}$ strings.

Is it known whether $|\text{im}(s)|/2^{512} \geq 0.5$?

If yes, what is the largest $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\text{im}(s)|/2^{512} \geq 1 - (1/2)^n$?

Comment: If we model SHA-512 as uniform random then this is answer; [SHA-512 - How difficult is it to find a hash digest beginning with at least twelve zeros?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89690/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka I interpret the question as "How close to surjective is SHA512". Assuming it is uniformly random also assumes it is surjective.

Comment: @meshcollider that was their previous question that Fgriue answered. In short, we don't know about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unknown but suspected to be the case. If we model SHA-512 as a pseudorandom function that is uniformly distributed on its codomain, a fixed output bin remains empty if all balls miss it.

Here we are throwing $k$ balls into $n$ bins.
An output bin remains empty if all the balls miss it which happens with a probability
$$
(1-1/n)^k = \left[(1-1/n)^n\right]^{k/n}<e^{-k/n}
$$
where $n=2^{512}$ and $k>n$. If we want this probability to be strictly less than $1/n^2$ we need to solve

$$
e^{-k/n}<\frac{1}{n^2}=e^{- 2 \ln n}
$$
which gives $k>2 n \ln n.$

We can now apply the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality) (which is weak but the question is about infinite domain size, so this is fine)
on the complement of this event and note that since there are $n$ bins the probability that *any* bin is empty is strictly less than $n(1/n^2)=1/n.$

This gives
$$
k>2^{513+\log_2 \ln 512}
$$
if I haven’t made a computational error.