# Finding the cleartext password given its MD5

Tags: hash, md5, key-recovery

Given powerful GPU and PC hardware, is it realistic to recover a password in a few hours given a cleartext's MD5? Max chars are 95, and the maximum length of the password is 15 characters.

Comment: Well, what's $log_2(95^{15})$? That's your maximum strength in bits (i.e. computer generated) password. It would be near 100 bits, that's well outside of any single PC, and likely even outside any computer configuration. I don't think that rainbow tables would help either.

Comment: But what about using GPU ?

Comment: Start calculating by using these. [How reassuring is 64-bit (in)security?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298). Why do you care MD5!

Comment: You don't need to go nearly that large.  Per [Terahash](https://twitter.com/TerahashCorp/status/1155112559206383616) a 13 (random) character password hashed with MD-5 would take over 300 years to brute force (using a fairly modern GPU).  Keep in mind that's a random password, human selected passwords can sometimes be brute forced using password topologies within days or even hours.