# How easy is it in 2022 to find a SHA1 collision?

Tags: sha-1

Most of the answers I can find date to years back where the first collision(s) were found, but hardware mainly GPUs have progressed a lot in the past few years (with for example the new line of 3090s coming).

How easy is it to do so right now?

Comment: Earlier computational work can be extended cheaply to find new collisions. I guess the question restricts to obtaining collisions independently of earlier work. There's [that](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014.pdf) relatively recent article, stating 8 GPU-years for a collision using GTX 1080 Ti, whatever that may be.

Comment: 1080 TI is outdated, and there are big performance upgrades in newer generations, and you can have a hundred or even thousand of those GPUs working.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is rather performance of the GPUs not about new improvements of the cryptographical attaks.

Comment: Does it really matter though? Performance of GPUs affects cryptographical attacks.

Comment: You are asking to compare them. You need to ask what is the current best attack that might use many different GPU/CPUs/ASIC to achieve their target.

Comment: The  $9,223,372,036,854,775,808 \approx 2^{63}$ so the [Summit can execute in one day and the collaborative powers of the Bitcoin miner can execute in one second.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298)

Comment: how about quantum attacks in speed to generate a collision?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

According to some [Hashcat benchmarks](https://openbenchmarking.org/test/pts/hashcat&eval=306f31f896ee6afac758df6db7589b6a2a232723#metrics), a current Nvidia GPU can compute SHA-1 hashes at a rate of:

> - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090    ~22.6×10<sup>9</sup> hashes per second
> - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti ~21.7×10<sup>9</sup> hashes per second

And AMD graphics cards seems to perform in the same range as per [this benchmark](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/99085955a1145ff61ec83512a50421a7):

> SHA-1 Speed.#1.........: 20.6×10<sup>9</sup>

Given its MSRP price of ~\$649, the AMD RX 6800 XT seems to be our best candidate to conduct a similar attack. (Notwithstanding any chip shortage driving the prices up like crazy...)

Next, according to the 2017 [shattered.it](https://shattered.it/) website and paper:

> This attack required over 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 SHA1 computations [9×10<sup>18</sup>]. This took the equivalent processing power as 6,500 years of single-CPU computations and 110 years of single-GPU computations.

But as mentioned in [fgrieu's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/99767/how-easy-is-it-in-2022-to-find-a-sha1-collision#comment215623_99767), in 2020, [a new paper ("SHA-1 is a Shambles")](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014.pdf) came out, further improving the SHAttered attack in which they estimated the cost of their attack to $~2^{61.6} = 3.5\times 10^{18}$ SHA-1 computations vs. the $2^{63}$ computations in the SHAttered one (see Table 4.)

We can thus compute that with the current GPUs it takes:

$$\frac{2^{61.6}}{20.6×10^9} \approx 169\times10^6$$

seconds with a single GPU, which is ~5.36 years.
But this parallelizes relatively well, so you could just add more GPUs to the mix and you could get one in six months with 10 GPUs, or in 2 months with 30 GPUs... And that's at a theoretical cost of ~\$19,470 of GPUs, plus ~ \$2,000 of electricity costs running your 30 GPUs for 2 months...

You can also just rent three p3.16xlarge AWS instance [with a hash rate of ~135GH/s](https://gist.github.com/iam1980/808f696a14b0c42b26621a01f91a8b18) each at a cost of ~\$24.48 per instance per hour, for a total of 405GH/s for \$73.44 per hour. That would take you ~2397.12 hours (3 months) and cost you ~\$176,044.

Remarkably, we can see that in only 5 years, we're down from an attack costing ~110 GPU years to an attack costing ~8 GPU-years in 2020 (thanks to theoretical improvements & newer GPUs) to just ~5.4 GPU years nowadays (thanks to newer, faster GPUs).

Also note that this is not taking possible ASICs into account, unlike [this 2021 paper ("On The Cost of ASIC Hardware Crackers: A SHA-1 Case Study")](https://www.pure.ed.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/208131275/On_The_Cost_CHATTOPADHYAY_DOA18022021_AFV.pdf) which answers your question when assuming custom ASICs are an option:

> In particular, we remark that the chosen-prefix collisions for SHA-1 can be generated in under a minute, with an ASIC cluster that costs a few dozen Millions dollars. Such ability would allow an attacker to apply the SLOTH attack on TLS or SSH connections using SHA-1.

Finally, if we take into account supercomputers and the Bitcoin network, [this question is already covered in this excellent answer by kelalaka from 2018](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/29574), and things aren't looking good: the Bitcoin network could do it in 1s, given its current hashrate of over 200TH/s... Yup: one second! But that's not technically true since Bitcoin's dedicated hardware is actually specialized in computing SHA-256 hashes.
In a more realistic way, it would take less than a day to do it on a super-computer such as the one owned by the US Department of Energy's Oak Ridge National Laboratory (ORNL) named "[Summit](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/summit/)".

Comment: Side note (no affiliation), but services like https://vast.ai cost between \$3 to \$5 per hour for 8x 3090s, so about the same speeds for this purpose. Another factor of eight down from the cost (~$25-35k). Though I love using Amazon as an example of GPU pricing for password cracking, actual costs can be much lower with other services, spot instances, etc.