# KDF based on X9.63 vs. NIST SP800-108

Tags: key-derivation, nist

What is the difference between KDF based on NIST SP800-108 vs. the older one in ANSI X9.63? When should one be selected over the other? Thanks.

Comment: ANSI X9.63 uses SHA-1, whereas  SP800-108 uses PRF based KDF.

Answer (score 3):

The ANSI [X9.63](ftp://ftp.iks-jena.de/mitarb/lutz/standards/ansi/X9/x963-7-5-98.pdf#page=33) uses SHA-1 for Key Derivation Function:

> Ingredients: The key derivation function employs the hash function SHA-1 specified in Section 5.6.2

NIST [SP800-108](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-108.pdf#page=10) uses PRFs:

> This Section defines several families of key derivation functions that use PRFs.

First look at their dates;

- 1998 : ANSI X9.63
- 2009 : NIST SP800-108

And, SHA-1 is no longer [recomended](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/hash-functions/nist-policy-on-hash-functions). So you should prefer NIST SP800-108

There are two other reasons for not to use SHA-1:

- SHA-1 is [shattered](https://shattered.io/), you can also read these two articles:

  - [Does “Shattered” actually show SHA-1-signed certificates are “unsafe”?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60640/does-shattered-actually-show-sha-1-signed-certificates-are-unsafe)
  - [After Google's collision attack, is RSA-SHA1 signature still safe?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60619/after-googles-collision-attack-is-rsa-sha1-signature-still-safe?noredirect=1&lq=1).
- Reaching $2^{80}$ for the generic birthday attack is not that far since the Bitcoin miners [reached](https://blockchain.info/en/charts/hash-rate?scale=1&timespan=all) $\approx2^{92}$ for SHA256 hashes per year in 06 Agust 2019.
- Also, SHA-256 is approximately 2.2 times slower than SHA-1 on [hashcat 2080Ti](https://www.onlinehashcrack.com/tools-benchmark-hashcat-gtx-1080-ti-1070-ti.php)

---

**Note:** Depending on your case, there is also [password-based key derivations](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf); as PBKDF2